# Characteristics of bad object oriented design

Tags: oop, design-principles

I am reading about object oriented design principles. I came across the characteristics of a bad design.

> 1. It is hard to change because every change affects too many other
>      parts of the system. (Rigidity)
> 2. When you make a change, unexpected parts of the system break.
>      (Fragility)
> 3. It is hard to reuse in another application because it cannot be
>      disentangled from the current application. (Immobility)

I am able to understand the first two but the third one is little difficult for me to understand. 
Is it about extracting common features of related classes in a Base class, making methods from the code which is repetitive ? But it says `hard to reuse in another Application.` Usually we write context specific code and `Over-engineering` is not a good idea, we have good principles like `YAGNI` (You ain't gonna need it) I find these ideas little contradicting.

Please provide your valuable thoughts for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobility example:

Assume the following classes:

1. Animal
2. Canine
3. Dog

As you would expect, `Canine` extends `Animal` and `Dog` extends `Canine`.

One way to poorly design `Animal` is to give it a method `talk()` which prints out `bark`. Perhaps, the original intent of this application was for dogs only and therefore the `talk` method barking was fine. But reusing this in another code base would lead to issues.

Say we want to extend `Animal` and create `Bird`. Birds don't bark :)

It's hard to image that someone would do this. But it happens all of the time. Base classes aren't abstracted out which leads to misplaced code making it difficult to correct/reuse.

One could argue that the `Bird` class could override the `talk` method. That would work, however, another developer extending `Animal` for yet another reason may forget to override that method... etc.

I know this isn't the best example, but it demonstrates the problem.